# Is this Android Studio bug or am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I have android studio setup on my Ubuntu machine and now whenever I try to start the emulator, it throws exception like:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>
> Output:
>
> PANIC: Could not find
> Nexus_S_API_21.ini file in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME$ nor in $HOME./android/avd

So when I do:

```
echo $ANDROID_AVD_HOME
```

It shows empty which means that this path is not set and when `$HOME` is my `/home/user`

So when I go in `/home/user/.android/avd` there is really no `.ini` file. So, I am confused, when I create a virtual device, where does it go? How can I find the path where virtual devices are being created and if possible, how can I change the path to create virtual devices?

Comment: For me, %avd_name%.ini files are in /home/user/.android/avd folder. This might be stupid, but did you try to recreate your avd?

Comment: I tried creating virtual device three times

Comment: Try to execute this: "%android_home%/tools/android list avd". It should show you created avds (you might see whether or not avds are created and exist). Also, did you try to start emulator from GUI: "%android_home%/tools/android avd" and then press "Start..." button?

Comment: take a look at genymotion for android/emulation . really good 4 ubuntu as long as you rm KVM .

Comment: @krossovochkin the command you provided is not working. And yes, I tried starting from GUI Tools->Android->AVD Manager

Comment: And what happens, when you try to start from avd manager? P.S. You might find location where avd stored in GUI right under tab "Android Virtual Devices" there is line: "List of existing Android Virtual Devices located at %here is location%"

Comment: @RobertRowntree Didn't get you man

Comment: @Mr.777 he said about genymotion emulator: https://www.genymotion.com

Comment: @krossovochkin wow so it's in /root :P

Comment: And i dont want it in /root, so how can I change it?

Comment: Try to set variable ANDROID_AVD_HOME for /home/user/.android/avd, for example. Restart and recreate avd, maybe it can help

Comment: Also you might can look for useful info here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78577

Comment: I have added like this: set $ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/home/user and then recreated the virtual device but nope

Comment: Well, I did it. Thanks @krossovochkin please add your details as answer.

Comment: How exactly you did it?)) Maybe it will be better if you add your step-by-step solution by yourself?

Comment: Well, I did it with your help, so you deserve it not me. I just changed the ANDROID_AVD_HOME to /home/user , restarted my IDE and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find location of your avd's *.ini files in AVD Manager (GUI).
Right under tab `"Android Virtual Devices"` there is line `"List of existing Android Virtual Devices located at %here is the location%"`.

You can try to change system variable `%android_avd_home%` to something like `/home/user`, for example and then restart IDE (Android Studio).

Also, you can try to find useful information here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78577

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same issue on OSX, but the weird part was it only happened after I had added the ANDROID_SDK_HOME varible to my environment.

I experimented and found that if I added the ANDROID_AVD_HOME variable to my environment or I removed ANDROID_SDK_HOME, it caused it to start working.

Answer (score 1):

One solution at this problem is to copy the file's emulator which exited and rename it in the name of the new emulator; that is say the android studio name of emulator who is try to run.

NB : Before I suppose you had install the eclipse ADT which contains one or some emulator

Example :
1) cd .android/avd/
2) ls -al
3) cp .ini .ini
4) Finish run the emulator in your android studio by the AVD

Comment: Please don't paste the exact same answer on multiple questions.  (And if you are going to do so, at least copy the edits I made on the other copy of this answer.  I'm only going to do them once.)

Answer (score 1):

This happens on *Windows* when **the user home folder is changed from the default** one. To make Android Studio happy just add a system enviroment variable and set it to your home folder, for example:

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOME = D:\Users\max\
```

Comment: Thanks, i had issues with setting the Environment Variable properly. This did the trick